# RegExp.prototype.exec() doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

```js
const fs = require('fs')

const jsdocFinder = /\/\*\*\n(.+?)\*\//gs
/**
 * Convert JSDocs from a file into JSON.
 * @function
 * @param    {String[]|String} dirs The directory or directories of the file(s) to convert.
 */
function interpret (dirs = []) {
  if (typeof dir === 'string') dirs = [dirs]
  const types = {}

  for (const dir of dirs) {
    const file = fs.readFileSync(dir, 'utf8')
    const docs = jsdocFinder.exec(file)

    console.log(docs)
  }

  return types
}

module.exports = interpret
```

This is my code for a function that's supposed to convert JSDocs to JSON data. In the `for` loop, I use a regex to capture any text in between `/**\n` and `*/`. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working on the files. I have logged what `file` equals and it should match. I have tested the Regex and it should work fine.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rsg3R.png

`docs` just equals `null` every time.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, since Windows uses CR LF, I need to do `\r\n`.